# Выполнение операций через определенное количество циклов

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, чтобы через определенное количество циклов выполнялось "что-то"?

Например у меня есть цикл `do .. while()`, в нем происходят определенные итерации, и я хочу, чтобы через 3 цикла к определенной переменной `i` прибавлялось число 2.

Comment: оператор if и оператор нахождения остатка от деления нацело.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте [оператор %](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[] { 3, 9, 11, 13, 17, 21 };
    this.Something(data);

}

public void Something(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var pos = 0;
    foreach (var element in data)
    {
        if (pos % 3 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"pos = {pos}, element = {element}, doubled = {2 * element}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"pos = {pos}, element = {element}");
        }
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Выведет:

> ```
> pos = 0, element = 3, doubled = 6
> pos = 1, element = 9
> pos = 2, element = 11
> pos = 3, element = 13, doubled = 26
> pos = 4, element = 17
> pos = 5, element = 21
> ```

Здесь 3 -- это величина шага (через три цикла), а ноль -- это смещение.

Можно например поменять условие на pos % 3 = 1 и получить такой вариант:

> ```
> pos = 0, element = 3
> pos = 1, element = 9, doubled = 18
> pos = 2, element = 11
> pos = 3, element = 13
> pos = 4, element = 17, doubled = 34
> pos = 5, element = 21
> ```

А для pos == 2 -- такой:

> ```
> pos = 0, element = 3
> pos = 1, element = 9
> pos = 2, element = 11, doubled = 22
> pos = 3, element = 13
> pos = 4, element = 17
> pos = 5, element = 21, doubled = 42
> ```

Принцип понятен?

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало )

Comment: @diraria  спасибо, проглядел.

Comment: @AK, а разве для варианта  `if (pos % 3 == 2)`, выведет `pos = 0, element = 3, doubled = 6; pos = 1, element = 9 и т.д.`?

Comment: @sp7 Вы правы, в изначальной версии поста было правильно, а потом я заредактировался и не ту версию скопировал. Поправил.

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю это ли вы ищете, но вот например я так делаю если нужно что-то сделать через определенное количество циклов. Он сначала запрашивает сколько раз нада разделить на 2 переменную е, а потом выводит в консоль все результаты.

```cs
using System;

namespace project {

    class Program {

        static void Main() {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int s = 0;
            for(int e=100; s!=i ; e/=2){
               System.Console.WriteLine(e);
               s++;}
            }
            }

        }
```

Comment: А чем это лучше прошлого варианта? И целочисленное деление тут вообще не нужно и тогда если упростить это превратится в обычный цикл, который выполнится столько раз, сколько указано в `i`, а не каждые 3 раза.